# Reject SSH connections from unlisted countries, using hosts.allow/hosts.deny on CentOS

Tags: bash, shell-script, hosts

I was trying for few hours to make my custom script work when using `hosts.allow/hosts.deny`, to prevent connections to SSH and other services supporting *TCP wrappers* from unlisted countries.

Example with SSH:

1. **hosts.deny** file

   `sshd : ALL`
2. **hosts.allow** file

   `sshd: ALL: spawn /usr/local/bin/country_filter %h`
3. **country_filter** script:

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Specify the two-letter ISO Country Code(s) to accept
ALLOW_COUNTRIES="RU\|CY" # list of country codes in the exampled format ("RU\|GR\|CY")

COUNTRY=`/usr/bin/geoiplookup $1 | /bin/grep -w $ALLOW_COUNTRIES`

[[ $COUNTRY ]] && RESPONSE="ALLOW" || RESPONSE="DENY"

if [ $RESPONSE = "ALLOW" ]
then
  echo "$RESPONSE"
  exit 0
else
  echo "$RESPONSE"
  exit 1
fi
```

---

The script above works great from console but I *could not* make it work, when using **hosts.allow**.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented in the `hosts_options(5)` man page, the standard output is redirected to `/dev/null`, so that there's no chance for you to get the output from `echo`. And as you want the exit status to be taken into account, you should use `aclexec` instead of `spawn`. Indeed the man page says for `aclexec`: "The connection will be allowed or refused depending on whether the command returns a true or false exit status."

Comment: At first, thank you for your answer! Yes, it's true for *Debian* distro and probaly for some other but it doesn't work at *CentOS*? Am I wrong?

Comment: As I state that it's for CentOS - it doesn't work that way and I already tried it. Here is the error in logs:  `sshd[25620]: error: /etc/hosts.allow, line 16: bad option name: "aclexec"`. Is there a way to get `aclexec` work?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Indeed, according to http://ts1-en.blogspot.fr/2009/06/ssh-access-control-with-geoip.html, for CentOS and other RedHat-based systems, you need `spawn`, but I wonder whether this is correct. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/s3-tcpwrappers-access-rules-comm.html says nothing about the exit status.

Comment: That's the case. I have no idea how to catch exit status.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev That's the goal of `aclexec` (when supported): it's like `spawn`, but also checks the exit status. I suggest that you fill a bug report against CentOS/RedHat so that they add `aclexec`.

Comment: It seems that, 6 years after this post, `aclexec` is still not supported on CentOS 7. @IliaRostovtsev : did you manage to get this working ?

Comment: There is an interesting work around [here](https://github.com/ProvinciaRC/geolite_scripts), where IP that try to access from a specified country are placed into an allow file so they can access _at their second attempt_